# iManage ImportCmd launching new instance of Word

Tags: .net, vb.net, vsto, imanage

I'm trying to save a Word document into iManage using ImportCmd from IMANEXTLib and I'm getting a new instance of Word every time I run it.

I've saved the document to doc1.doc, and then:

```
    'Connects to WorkSite
    Dim dmsConnection As IManage.IManDMS = New IManage.ManDMSClass()
    dmsConnection.ApplicationName = "My Application"
    Dim sesCobbDms As IManage.IManSession = dmsConnection.Sessions.Add("DMS")
    sesCobbDms.TrustedLogin()

    'Initialisation
    Dim hwndWord As Integer
    Dim strTempCaption As String = Application.Caption
    Application.Caption = "Hunting For Word"
    hwndWord = MyApi.FindWindow("OpusApp", Application.Caption)
    Application.Caption = strTempCaption
    Dim intKeepCheckedOut As Integer
    Dim docJustSaved As IManage.NRTDocument
    Dim objImportCmd As IMANEXTLib.ImportCmd
    Dim objContextItems As New IMANEXTLib.ContextItems

    'Sets up ContextItems ready for save process
    objContextItems.Add("ParentWindow", hwndWord)
    objContextItems.Add("DestinationObject", sesCobbDms)
    objContextItems.Add("IManExt.Import.FileName", NrPort & "\Doc1.doc")
    'Note that we have to check it in and then back out again, otherwise it checks out to the wrong place
    intKeepCheckedOut = IManage.CheckinOptions.nrDontKeepCheckedOut
    objContextItems.Add("IManExt.Import.KeepCheckedOut", intKeepCheckedOut)
    'Forces a blank description
    objContextItems.Add("ImanExt.Import.DocDescription", "")


    objImportCmd = New IMANEXTLib.ImportCmd
    objImportCmd.Initialize(objContextItems)
    objImportCmd.Update()

    If objImportCmd.Status = IMANEXTLib.CommandStatus.nrActiveCommand Then
        'Imports the document, throwing a Save As screen at the user
        objImportCmd.Execute()
```

And at this point, I get a new instance of Word, on top of the one I was saving from (ie, on top of Application).  What gives?

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to do something very similar.

But falling at the first hurdle!

I have used IManage before and do so by adding a reference to Interop.IManage (which is in the GAC).

How do I add a reference to IManExt ???

Thanks

Comment: @SteveCl  You'll need to use tlbimp to create an Interop DLL for the COM DLL, and then import it into the GAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide a resolution, I noticed that the problem only occurred under one user account (mine) and then I just deleted my user profile.  My shiny! new! profile doesn't have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this doesn't seem like a cop-out, but I'd contact Interwoven supprot (or whomever has bought them out this month).

Comment: Autonomy are the people who bought them out this month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `save` command other than iManage. For testing, you can create a demo word document and then try to save the word document from within the `MS WORD` application itself just to check which pop up window is visible. If the document is getting saved as with the desired normal behaviour then it means there is problem with your code but if again a new word application is getting opened then its a problem with your application.

You can probably try for both `Save As` and `local Save As` using iManage within the `MS WORD` application. If both works fine then try with an alternative `save` command in your code.